# c# picturebox new file instance

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a windows form application with a picturebox.
A foreach loop does some work and loads a jpeg file into the picturebox each time.
I need to load the file in a way that wont stop the source images from being deleted by other processes. I think I need to somehow create a new instance of the image when I load it but I just cant figure out how to do that. Have been searching stack overflow, google etc - no luck.

```
    imagePreviewBox.Load(Dir + "\\" + file);
```

Comment: "I need to load the file in a way that wont stop the source images from being deleted by other processes." > I dont know what you mean with this. Be more speciffic.

Comment: PictureBox.Load() already puts a lock on the file.  You are trying to solve a problem that you don't have.

Comment: OK I probably explained poorly since I'm a novice.
Lets say I want to delete the file that is loaded in the picturebox, so I go picturebox.Image = null;
If I then go to delete the image file, the picturebox still seems to have a lock on it and I get an exception.

Comment: I can call picturebox.Dispose();
which does the trick, but then I cant use the picturebox again.

Comment: try `picturebox.Image.Dispose();` instead.